# Does WFFM Reporting in CMS works only with InProc Session State?

Tags: wffm, session-state

We are using the Sitecore WFFM version 8.1 Update-2 installed in Sitecore version 8.1 rev 160302. Our CMS site session state is configured to use "StateServer". We are using the SqlDataProvider to store the form submission data, and were able to write the data to the WFFM SQL Database.

Now, in the CMS, when we are trying to view the WFFM Reports, we see the below error related to session state. It seems if the "SessionState" of the CMS site is set to value other than "InProc", I see this error.

> 7372 14:54:47 ERROR Application error.
>   Exception: System.Web.HttpException
>   Message: Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.
>   Source: System.Web
>      at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.WriteValueToStreamWithAssert(Object value, BinaryWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Serialize(BinaryWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.Serialize(SessionStateStoreData item, Stream stream)
>      at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.SerializeStoreData(SessionStateStoreData item, Int32 initialStreamSize, Byte[]& buf, Int32& length, Boolean compressionEnabled)
>      at System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)
>      at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>   Message: Type 'Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Wrappers.UI.ClientPageWrapper' in Assembly 'Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions, Version=8.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
>   Source: mscorlib
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
>      at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>      at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer)

Does the WFFM Reporting module in CM works only if the session state is set to "InProc"?

Comment: Have you checked this link yet? 
https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/unable-to-serialize-the-session-state-in-stateserver-and-sqlserver-mode/
Not sure for the version you mentioned but for previous it would only work in InProc

Comment: I checked it now. The ClientPageWrapper class is not marked as serializable. I am not sure if Sitecore has any workaround for this particular issue.

Comment: Can you set to InProc? I had an issue with serialization and using InProc fixed without the need to mark the classes as serializable

Comment: It works with InProc. The problem is with the "StateServer" mode, which we are using for our CMS site.